# ngFor is not showing any data

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to bind some data to the template with `Angular 6`, so this is the `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = +params['id'];
    });
    let url = this.baseUrl + `/items/${this.id}`;
    this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe((data : Array<any>)=> {
        this.ItemToEdit = data;
    });
}
```

Here is the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of ItemToEdit?.results">
              <div class="col-sm-8 float-left">

                <mat-form-field> <input matInput
                  class="form-control" placeholder="Item name"
                  formControlName="name" id="ItemName" value='{{ item.name }}'>
                </mat-form-field>

              </div>
</div>
```

The variable `ItemToEdit` is like following:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "alias": [
        "first"
      ], 
      "apps": [], 
      "description": "this is an item", 
      "id": 1, 
      "name": "item342"
    }
  ]
}
```

So, the problem is when I open the template (via some button), the HTML that has the ngFor directive does not show (the div that has the ngFor becomes blank). I don't know how to show the data ... the variable `ItemToEdit` has only one value (length = 1) but as it has a nested array called `results` I show data through the for loop. When I try to do something like this inside typescript:

```
  this.loadedName = this.ItemToEdit.results[0].name;
```

I get an error saying `ItemToEdit.results` not defined

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Found out that my code works but only after refreshing the page...

The server intermittently returns responses like this instead of the expected results:

- `{ "error": "(_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away') [SQL: 'SELECT .... }`
- `{ "error": "(_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) (2014, \"Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now\") [SQL: 'SELECT ......" }`

**================ EDIT 2 ===============**

I was getting the Mysql exception because I'm making another httpRequest inside ngOnInit to fill a select field from database .... 
After deleting that request, my code works fine.

Comment: Mh, since the  `this.ItemToEdit = data` is executed a bit later, can you please add a `isLoading = false`, set it to true after the ` this.ItemToEdit = data` and add a div with an ngIf outside the ngFor?

Comment: Maybe the value of `url` is incorrect when calling `httpClient`. Try moving the last 2 statements of `ngOnInit` inside the `route.params.subscribe` callback.

Comment: @ConnorsFan that didn't work

Comment: On your subscription to httpClient, you defined data as `Array<any>`. This and the line `this.ItemToEdit = data;` makes the access of `ItemToEdit?.results` invalid, as `ItemToEdit` is an array itself. if you found that itemToEdit has just one Element (and this is what you are looking for), change your access to `ItemToEdit[0].results` in the template and.`ItemToEdit[0].results[0].name` in the typescript code.

Comment: Just replace html `let item of ItemToEdit?.results` with `let item of ItemToEdit`. and replace ts `this.ItemToEdit = data;` with `this.ItemToEdit = data ? data.results : []`

Comment: @JürgenRöhr it gives: `ItemToEdit[0] undefined`

Comment: @ShashikantDevani that didn't work I still get a blank page.

Comment: Can you post your whole `data` in your question, when you get in result.

Comment: I did. Please check.

Comment: Can you please make `console` when you get data in your ts : `console.log('data :', data.results[0].name`.

Comment: How to show the fields inside the json without a for loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing `ngOnInit` method has problems:

1. It reads `this.id` before `this.id` has an opportunity to be set.
2. It doesn't update `this.ItemToEdit` when `this.id` changes.
3. `this.id` might not match the actual ID of the currently loaded data.

The following suggested implementation solves these problems by:

1. waiting until the ID is retrieved before making HTTP requests,
2. only updating `this.id` when data is available in `this.ItemToEdit`, and
3. cancelling any pending HTTP request if the ID changes before it's fulfulled.

```
ngOnInit() {
    let itemToEditID;
    const httpObservable = this.route.params.pipe(
        map(params => +params['id']),
        tap(newID => itemToEditID = newID),
        switchMap(newID => this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseUrl}/items/${newID}`))
    );
    this.sub = httpObservable.subscribe(data => {
        this.id = itemToEditID;
        this.ItemToEdit = data;
    });
}
```

Placing `<pre>{{ ItemToEdit | json }}</pre>` somewhere in your template allowed you to inspect the server's actual output, which allowed you to identify frequent errors coming from the server.

The good news about those errors is that they're caused by the server and not your code.  The bad news is that you'll need to determine what's wrong with the server and how to fix that—but that's a topic for another question.

Depending on your needs, you may wish to output the server error on your page when one occurs:

```
<div *ngIf="ItemToEdit?.error" class="danger">
    <h2>An error occurred while trying to retrieve item {{ id }}</h2>
    <p>{{ error }}</p>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let item of ItemToEdit?.results">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I appreciate, I tried that and I still get same thing, blank div

Comment: Consider putting `<pre>{{ ItemToEdit | json }}</pre>` somewhere in your template to identify exactly whether it's an issue with the data being returned, or something else.

Comment: this is what I got: `{
  "error": "(_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away') [SQL: 'SELECT  ....
}` or another error also: `{
  "error": "(_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) (2014, \"Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now\") [SQL: 'SELECT ......"
}`

Comment: **This is bad, but also good.**  Bad because your server has some sort of issue that needs fixing, but good because it means that your code is not causing the problem.  You'll need to speak to whoever manages the server, sending them that information.

Comment: I'm the one managing this API REST ... I should may be look somewhere else ... Thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer with how to get UI feedback when server errors occur, so that at least in the meantime, you know what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

try to keep all your process in async

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (itemToEdit$ | async)">
    <div class="col-sm-8 float-left">

    <mat-form-field> <input matInput
      class="form-control" placeholder="Item name"
      formControlName="name" id="ItemName" value='{{ item.name }}'>
    </mat-form-field>

    </div>
</div>
```

in your component:

```
private itemToEdit$: Observable<any>;

....

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = +params['id'];
        let url = this.baseUrl + `/items/${this.id}`;
        this.itemToEdit$ = this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(
          map(data => data['results'])
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: it is giving TypeError: "_this.httpClient.get(...).map is not a function

Comment: yes i forgot the pipe and maybe you need to add the map operator from rxjs,

Comment: like this *import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';*

Comment: check the return of your api in network panel in chrome. If you don't have error it's just maybe because you don't retrieve data.

Comment: ... but did you get the data. And is it formatted to be return like *data['results']* in the map operator

Comment: check your http Response

Answer (score 0):

```
test: any = [];  
ngOnInit() {
        this.service.test().subscribe(res => {
          this.test = res.results;
        });
```

Html:

```
 <p *ngFor="let test of this.test">
   {{test.name}}
 </p>
```

if you need to bind it to input field just assign it with: `[value]="test?.name"`

service:

```
test(): Observable<any>{
return this.http.get(url);
}
```

Comment: this gives me in the console: `ERROR in src/app/item.component.ts(63,43): error TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'any[]'.`

Answer (score 0):

The preferred solution, would be to use `async` as defined in the answer by **antoine-clavijo**.

Alternatively, if your component (or parents) are defined using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, for example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './config.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

... you can tell Angular that the component needs to be updated, like this:

```
constructor(
  private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, 
  private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.id = +params['id'];
  });
  const url = this.baseUrl + `/items/${this.id}`;
  this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe((data: Array<any>)=> {
    this.ItemToEdit = data;
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I keep getting mysql exception: Commands out of sync

Comment: In the service are you caching the DB connection, or opening a new one?

Comment: I get data from a flask API REST. I have one connection and one session that I close after every commit and rollback if any exception. I use try cach in every service. Did I answer your question please ?

Comment: I am not familiar with the Flask API REST framework, so I can't help with that, but the evidence suggests the service is not handling multiple requests correctly.  Ultimately, you need to solve that first.